# piplyr package python

Tags: python, sql

Has anyone heard about "piplyr" package in python? It has several functions similar to "dplyr" and "tidyr".

I am trying to follow its instruction here https://pypi.org/project/piplyr. However, I get an error saying the 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'sort_values'. Below I have provided the example:

```
import pandas as pd
from piplyr.main import piplyr

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[2,1,20,10],"C":['a','a','b','b']})
pi = piplyr(df)
(
 pi.
   group_by('C').
     sort_by("A")
).to_df
```

I can get to the results I am looking for using the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[2,1,20,10],"C":['a','a','b','b']})
pi = piplyr(df)
(
    pi.
  sql_plyr(''' 
  SELECT A, C
  FROM df
  GROUP BY C,A
  ORDER BY A
  
  ''')
).to_df
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using piplyr. This is related to the fact that after applying the group by clause, Pandas does not render a data frame, but rather a 'groupby' object. So, I plan to remove the group_by function from the package in the next version.To solve this problem, I added four functions to the package: mutate_eval, mutate_func, sql_plyr, and summarize. These functions enable users to perform group by operations.